# Retrieving statistics about URL clicks

Tags: c#, asp.net, beginner, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm pretty new to ASP/MVC but have had some prior programming experience.

I am trying to retrieve statistics about URL clicks - total clicks and unique clicks by IP address. I started with:

```
ViewBag.ClicksToday = context.EmailLinkClicks
     .Where(c => c.CreatedOn == DateTime.Today).Count();

ViewBag.ClicksWeek = context.EmailLinkClicks
     .Where(c => c.CreatedOn > System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.AddDays(c.CreatedOn, -7)).Count();

ViewBag.ClicksMonth = context.EmailLinkClicks
     .Where(c => c.CreatedOn.Month == DateTime.Today.Month).Count();

ViewBag.UniqueClicksToday = context.EmailLinkClicks.Where(c => c.CreatedOn == DateTime.Today)
     .Select(c => c.IPAddress).Distinct().Count();

ViewBag.UniqueClicksWeek = context.EmailLinkClicks.Where(c => c.CreatedOn > System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.AddDays(c.CreatedOn, -7))
     .Select(c => c.IPAddress).Distinct().Count();

ViewBag.UniqueClicksMonth = context.EmailLinkClicks.Where(c => c.CreatedOn.Month == DateTime.Today.Month)
     .Select(c => c.IPAddress).Distinct().Count();
```

Then I thought why not make it a function:

```
private static int GetClicks(AppContext context, string period, bool unique)
{
    int Clicks = 0;
    switch (period)
    {
        case "today":
            var ClicksToday = context.EmailLinkClicks
                .Where(c => c.CreatedOn == DateTime.Today);
            Clicks = unique ? ClicksToday.Select(c => c.IPAddress).Distinct().Count()
                : ClicksToday.Count();
            break;
        case "week":
            var ClicksWeek = context.EmailLinkClicks
                .Where(c => c.CreatedOn > System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.AddDays(c.CreatedOn, -7));
            Clicks = unique ? ClicksWeek.Select(c => c.IPAddress).Distinct().Count()
                : ClicksWeek.Count();
            break;
        case "month":
            var ClicksMonth = context.EmailLinkClicks
                .Where(c => c.CreatedOn.Month == DateTime.Today.Month);
            Clicks = unique ? ClicksMonth.Select(c => c.IPAddress).Distinct().Count()
                : ClicksMonth.Count();
            break;
    }
    return Clicks;
}
```

But I still have to call quite a lot of code:

```
ViewBag.ClicksToday = GetClicks(context, "today", false);
ViewBag.ClicksWeek = GetClicks(context, "week", false);
ViewBag.ClicksMonth = GetClicks(context, "month", false);

ViewBag.UniqueClicksToday = GetClicks(context, "today", true);
ViewBag.UniqueClicksWeek = GetClicks(context, "week", true);
ViewBag.UniqueClicksMonth = GetClicks(context, "month", true);
```

My questions:

1. Is there any way to further simplify/reduce this code?

   - perhaps have the total & unique in one value? [total],[unique]
2. Is it poor practice to pass **period** as a string and then interrogate it?
3. Where should you store these kind of database queries? It currently resides in my controller and then returned to the view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the first thing I came up with. Wrote it in Notepad, so it might not compile exactly as is.

```
private static int GetClicks(AppContext context, Period period, bool unique)
{
    int Clicks = 0;
    switch (period)
    {
        var query = context.EmailLinkClicks.AsQueryable();
        case Period.Today:
            query = query.Where(c => c.CreatedOn == DateTime.Today);
            break;
        case Period.Week:
            query = query.Where(c => c.CreatedOn > System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.AddDays(c.CreatedOn, -7));
            break;
        case Period.Month:
            query = query.Where(c => c.CreatedOn.Month == DateTime.Today.Month);
            break;
    }

    var ipAddresses = query.Select(c => c.IpAddress);

    if (unique)
    {
        query = query.Distinct();
    }

    return query.Count();
}

enum Period 
{
    Today,
    Week,
    Month
}
```

**Update:** As to where to store these queries... Doing it in your controller isn't the worst thing in the world. There are a ton of different places you could put that code though. The Repository pattern seems to be popular. I'm not strict about that kind of thing though.

**Update:** if you wanted to get both the total and unique stats in the same call, you could do something like this: https://gist.github.com/alexdresko/8059762/bcf233b86869042c4b6f360f6b461999b2bf4899

**Update:** But what you probably want, assuming you want to create some kind of report, is this: https://gist.github.com/alexdresko/8059762/c4afa948f020e8395bb27d565269c914aad926a7

That one will allow you to simply iterate over the collections of stats in your view, display all relevant information.

Comment: Good advice in general, but: 1. I'm not completely sure about the use of `.AsQueryable()`, I think the omitting that and explicitly specifying the type of `query` would be cleaner. 2. What happens when `period` has an invalid value? 3. You're not using `ipAddresses` anywhere, which means you're not calculating the case when `unique == true` correctly.

Comment: 1. You _have_ to use AsQueryable() or the query chaining I'm doing in the example won't work. 2. Period won't have an invalid value because I'm using an enum. 3. Oops, you're right about that. I did mention in my OP that I wrote that code in notepad.

Comment: 1. You don't, you can write `IQueryable<EmailLinkClick> query = context.EmailLinkClicks;` and it will work. 2. That's not how `enum`s work in .Net, you can always do something like `(Period)42` and you're going to get an invalid value.

Comment: 1. What's the difference between what you wrote and what I wrote, except that mine is quite a bit shorter? 2. Who does that? :) And how would you get around it without a bunch of silly code?

Comment: 1. The difference is very small, yes. I *think* that my approach makes it easier to understand what does the line actually do. But your way is okay too. 2. I don't think `default: throw InvalidOperationException();`, or something like that is silly code.

Comment: 1. Ah, the var/no-var debate. I'm pro-var. You'd have a hard time convincing me that this is a bad place to use var. But, 2, you did convince me that the default: is a good idea. :) I likely won't remember to do that 99% of the time, but it's a good idea. :)

Comment: Thanks Alex. I amended your code slightly. I've been reading online and a lot of people seem to disapprove of the ViewBag/Data concepts and favour strongly-typed models. So what I did was put the Stats class and Period Enum in the EmailLinksClick class and then return the model back to the partial view. Then simply loop through the @model List<Models.Stats> object.

Comment: Very good @JakkyD. That's absolutely the better thing to do in this case.